# Import and export BPMN 2.0 XML into / from MS Visio 2010

Tags: xml, visio, bpmn

I want to export my BPMN diagrams from Visio 2010 Premium to BPMN 2.0 XML format, which is not default supported by Microsoft, this is their answer:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visiogeneral/thread/dc22aa3a-b347-4b9e-af2b-f7c1c80a7c49/

So, I went searching for some third party plugins, what I found uptil now is only this:

http://bpmn4visio.blogspot.com/

It looks great, but alas, it does not generate proper XML diagrams that are accepted by an XML validator like this:

http://tools.qennix.com/index.php

Does anyone know a method or plugin that does work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone wondering how to do this, I found a commercial plugin which works very good from ITP Commerece, but alas (very) pricy for just needing to import and export BPMN:

http://www.itp-commerce.com/en/process-modeler/

Answer (score 2):

Import of BPMN models into Visio and export of Visio BPMN models compatible with all tools supporting official BPMN 2.0 standard is available by using [Enterprise Explorer](http://enterprise-explorer.com/). It is a commercial tool, although it is not Visio plug-in. It can export and import any Visio models created with regular BPMN stencils shipped by Microsoft along with Visio Professional.

[The list of tools supporting BPMN process interchange](http://bpmn-miwg.github.io/bpmn-miwg-tools/) is maintained on GitHub, updated and automatically tested for all new submissions by [OMG BPMN Model Interchange Working Group (BPMN MIWG)](http://www.omgwiki.org/bpmn-miwg/doku.php).