# Convert file format from VSDX to BPMN file

Tags: javascript, visio, bpmn

Is this possible to convert the file from .vsdx file to  .bpmn file?
I m new from this visio. I need to change the file format to my project. Is there any conversion tool please inform. or any idea to using program language also welcome

Comment: This appears to be off-topic on stackoverflow (asking for a tool). Anyways, currently there is no stock solution available. You may want to check the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240157/import-and-export-bpmn-2-0-xml-into-from-ms-visio-2010

Comment: No, but it is possible to create a bpdi file from a conforming visio diagram if you know how. It does depend on what application you are using (I can't remember which applications natively use a `.bpmn` extension).

Comment: Yes I searched so many ways I found one of the online purchase tool in this website - 'signavio.com'.  But I want free tool or write a code to js

Comment: Then you are out of luck. There are currently not free solutions to do that. Doing that yourself is your only option then. Also, you can vote for the corresponding feature on the Microsoft website: https://visio.uservoice.com/forums/229400-visio-on-desktop/suggestions/5314502-bpmn-2-0-import-export